# Why can't I kill a timeout called from a Bash script with a keystroke?

Tags: bash, shell-script, kill, signals

[Edit: This looks similar to some other questions asking how to kill all spawned processes – the answers all seem to be to use pkill. So the core of my question may be: Is there a way to propagate Ctrl-C/Z to all processes spawned by a script?]

When calling a SoX `rec` with the `timeout` command from coreutils (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581821/738675)), there doesn't seem to be any way to kill it with a keystroke once it's been invoked from within a Bash script.

Examples:

```
timeout 10 rec test.wav
```

...can be killed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> from bash, but not when it's been called from inside a script.

```
timeout 10 ping nowhere
```

...can be killed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> from bash, and with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> when it's run from inside a script.

I can find the process ID and kill it that way, but why can't I use a standard break keystroke? And is there any way to structure my script so that I can?

Comment: Ctrl+Z does not kill processes, only pauses them. They will keep running if you give the `bg` of `fg` commands. Anyway, is there a difference between your 1st and 3d examples?

Comment: I don't have `timeout` on my system but killing `sleep` works whether it's typed directly on the command line, sourced, executed, or passed through the interpreter explicitly

Comment: @terdon Thanks, I've clarified the examples.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Signal keys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> send a signal to all processes in the foreground [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group).

In the typical case, a process group is a pipeline. For example, in `head <somefile | sort`, the process running `head` and the process running `sort` are in the same process group, as is the shell, so they all receive the signal. When you run a job in the background (`somecommand &`), that job is in its own process group, so pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't affect it.

The `timeout` program places itself in its own process group. From the source code:

```
/* Ensure we're in our own group so all subprocesses can be killed.
   Note we don't just put the child in a separate group as
   then we would need to worry about foreground and background groups
   and propagating signals between them.  */
setpgid (0, 0);
```

When a timeout occurs, `timeout` goes through the simple expedient of killing the process group of which it is a member. Since it has put itself in a separate process group, its parent process will not be in the group. Using a process group here ensures that if the child application forks into several processes, all its processes will receive the signal.

When you run `timeout` directly on the command line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the resulting SIGINT is received both by `timeout` and by the child process, but not by interactive shell which is `timeout`'s parent process. When `timeout` is called from a script, only the shell running the script receives the signal: `timeout` doesn't get it since it's in a different process group.

You can set a signal handler in a shell script with the `trap` builtin. Unfortunately, it's not that simple. Consider this:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo Interrupted at $(date)' INT
date
timeout 5 sleep 10
date
```

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after 2 seconds, this still waits the full 5 seconds, then print the “Interrupted” message. That's because the shell refrains from running the trap code while a foreground job is active.

To remedy this, run the job in the background. In the signal handler, call `kill` to relay the signal to the `timeout` process group.

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'kill -INT -$pid' INT
timeout 5 sleep 10 &
pid=$!
wait $pid
```

Comment: Very sneaky - worked beautifully! I am much smarter now, merci!

Comment: @marwan-alsabbagh answer seems more elegant and simpler, but won't kill any child processes. On this alternative we must `test -d /proc/$pid && kill -INT -$pid` to avoid `No such process` while Ctrl+Cing after `wait`.

Answer (score 29):

Building on the excellent answer provided by Gilles. The timeout command has a foreground option, if used then a CTRL+C will exit the timeout command.

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo caught interrupt and exiting;exit' INT
date
timeout --foreground 5 sleep 10
date
```

Comment: This is a great answer - simpler than the accepted answer and worked fine for me, using `timeout` from GNU coreutils.

Comment: More elegant, but won't kill any child processes

Answer (score 1):

Basically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a `SIGINT` signal, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Z send a `SIGTSTP` signal.

`SIGTSTP` just stops the process, a `SIGCONT` will continue it.

This works on the foreground-process that was forked on the command-line.

If your process is a background-process you will have to send that signal to the processes in a different way. `kill` will do that. In theory a "-"-operator on that kill should also signal child processes but this seldom works as expected.

For further reading: [**Unix-Signals**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal)

Comment: This is true, at least up to “seldom works as expected” (which depends on your expectations — you should read up about process groups), but completely irrelevant. The question does not betray any confusion about SIGINT and SIGTSTP.