# shell script: No such file or directory while running with bash command

Tags: bash, shell-script, fedora

Trying to run the [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script without +x execution permission using bash command.

```
bash wait-for-it.sh google.com:80
```

> timeout: failed to run command ‘wait-for-it.sh’: No such file or
> directory
>
> wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for
> google.com:80

(The error message, 2nd line of which comes from [inside the script](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh#L65), is same for above case even if execution permission is given)

But it works when directly executed given +x.

```
./wait-for-it.sh google.com:80
```

> wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for google.com:80
>
> wait-for-it.sh: google.com:80 is available after 1 seconds

Any way I can use the script without giving it execution permission, or debug the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) script. You can see the following function:

```bash
wait_for_wrapper()
{
    # In order to support SIGINT during timeout: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57692
    if [[ $WAITFORIT_QUIET -eq 1 ]]; then
        timeout $WAITFORIT_BUSYTIMEFLAG $WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT $0 --quiet --child --host=$WAITFORIT_HOST --port=$WAITFORIT_PORT --timeout=$WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT &
    else
        timeout $WAITFORIT_BUSYTIMEFLAG $WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT $0 --child --host=$WAITFORIT_HOST --port=$WAITFORIT_PORT --timeout=$WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT &
    fi
    WAITFORIT_PID=$!
    trap "kill -INT -$WAITFORIT_PID" INT
    wait $WAITFORIT_PID
    WAITFORIT_RESULT=$?
    if [[ $WAITFORIT_RESULT -ne 0 ]]; then
        echoerr "$WAITFORIT_cmdname: timeout occurred after waiting $WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT seconds for $WAITFORIT_HOST:$WAITFORIT_PORT"
    fi
    return $WAITFORIT_RESULT
}
```

If you look at this line:

```bash
timeout $WAITFORIT_BUSYTIMEFLAG $WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT $0 --quiet ...
```

Now if you run `bash wait-for-it.sh google.com:80` this will fail for two reasons:

1. The file `wait-for-it.sh` will not be recognized if this one is not defined inside the `$PATH` environment variable.
2. The file `wait-for-it.sh` has no execution permissions:

> Trying to run the wait-for-it.sh script without +x execution permission

Now, if you see the function, this one is passing the value of `$0`, where `$0` is the filename (`wait-for-it.sh`).
So what `timeout $WAITFORIT_BUSYTIMEFLAG $WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT $0` does is basically "run itself" (but with some args) using the `timeout` command:

```bash
timeout $WAITFORIT_BUSYTIMEFLAG $WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT wait-for-it.sh --quiet ...
```

The solution is using an absolute path or relative path when you run `wait-for-it.sh` with bash. You also need to assign the execution permissions to that file.

```bash
#Using relative path:
bash ./wait-for-it.sh google.com:80
#Using absolute path:
bash /path/to/wait-for-it.sh google.com:80
#e.g.
bash /home/user/wait-for-it.sh google.com:80
```

#### Why does "bash wait-for-it.sh google.com:80" fail?

You can edit the function `wait_for_wrapper` like this:

```bash
wait_for_wrapper()
{
   echo Running "$0"
   echo Whereis "$0": $(whereis "$0")
   $0
   echo Exit...
   exit #to avoid running the following code
    # In order to support SIGINT during timeout: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57692
    if [[ $WAITFORIT_QUIET -eq 1 ]]; then
        timeout $WAITFORIT_BUSYTIMEFLAG $WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT $0 --quiet --child --host=$WAITFORIT_HOST --port=$WAITFORIT_PORT --timeout=$WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT &
    else
        timeout $WAITFORIT_BUSYTIMEFLAG $WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT $0 --child --host=$WAITFORIT_HOST --port=$WAITFORIT_PORT --timeout=$WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT &
    fi
    WAITFORIT_PID=$!
    trap "kill -INT -$WAITFORIT_PID" INT
    wait $WAITFORIT_PID
    WAITFORIT_RESULT=$?
    if [[ $WAITFORIT_RESULT -ne 0 ]]; then
        echoerr "$WAITFORIT_cmdname: timeout occurred after waiting $WAITFORIT_TIMEOUT seconds for $WAITFORIT_HOST:$WAITFORIT_PORT"
    fi
    return $WAITFORIT_RESULT
}
```

If you run `bash wait-for-it.sh google.com:80` (with execution perms) you will get this error:

```
Running wait-for.sh at /home/user/...
Whereis wait-for.sh: wait-for.sh:
wait-for.sh: line 56: wait-for.sh: command not found
Exit...
```

As I said before, the line `$0` is trying to execute `wait-for.sh` but this one is not in any of directories of the `$PATH` env variable.

Now I will change the filename `wait-for.sh` to `ls`. The ls command will be recognized because my `$PATH` contains the dir `/usr/bin/` which is where `ls` is usually located. So, if you run:

```bash
bash ls  google.com:80
```

You will get:

```
Running ls at /home/user/...
Whereis ls ls: /usr/bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1p/ls.1p.gz /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz

#This output is of my $HOME directory:
 Postman         Templates        projects        
 bin             go               ls  
 Public          Videos           Documents         
 Downloads       Pictures         temp
Exit...
```

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth explanation, that helped man!

Comment: @AshNazg a pleasure! Every day is a learning experience :)